# Sequence of subspaces of $\ [ 0,2{\pi} ]$ with length that goes to $\ 0 $ 

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Can you give me an example of a sequence of subspaces of $\ [0,2{\pi}] $ that the legth of them tends to $\ 0 $ but for every $\ x \in [0,2{\pi}]$ there are infinitely many of them such as  x lives in them but also infinitely many of them such that x doesn't live in them?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more: what did you try? why you think such a sequence exists? Why do you tag it fourier-analysis?

Comment: I think it can solve a problem of Stein,Fourier analysis(a collegue of mine thought it is a nice problem and gave it me-but i dont know fourier analysis!).So with elementary knowledge i was trying to find a sequence of functions that the integral of their squares tend to 0 but the f_n(x) does not converge at no x.

Comment: For your comment, it sounds like a slowly oscillating sequence of functions should work.  Although it depends on which topology you have in mind for the last sentence.

Comment: For each x it is a sequence of numbers so the usual topology of R.I ws thinking F_n be everywhere 0 exept an interval of lenght that goes to 0 where say f_n =1.But i need at every x an oscillation between 0 and 1.That's why i need this sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Let $\iota : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,2\pi]$  be an enumeration. Now take $A_n = [\iota(n) - 1/n, \iota(n) + 1/n] \cap [0,2\pi]$.</strike>

As pointed out by chandok the previous answer was wrong.
$$B_{n,k} = [2\pi (k-1) 2^{-n}, 2\pi (k +1) 2^{-n}] \cap [0,2\pi]$$ for $0\leq k \leq n$ and use $ B_{0,0}, B_{0,1}, B_{1,0}, B_{1,1}, B_{1,2}, B_{2,0}, \dots $ as a solution.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that every $x \in [0; 2\pi]$ is in some interval $A_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @Alexander Thumm I edited the question because it was not going to solve my problem(see comments under my question).My mistake

Comment: @t.spero: The new answer also solves your new question. Also note, that these intervals are tightly related to the standard example of the sequence of functions you are trying to construct.

Comment: Btw, you can make my first idea work by restricting to those enumerations $\iota : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q \cap [0,2\pi]$ satisfying $|\iota(n-1) - \iota(n)| < 1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Or more generally $A_n = [\iota(n) - a_n, \iota(n) + a_n]\cap [0,2\pi]$ and $|\iota(n-1) - \iota(n)| < a_n$ for a positive sequence $a_n$ with $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n = \infty$.

Comment: @Alexander Thumm Or i can use the final answer without $\ 2^n $ but just $\ n$ in the denominator.In this way the division of $\ [0,2  {\pi} ]$ is more smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Without extra assumptions this seems quite easy.  Take the Cantor construction but do not throw anything away, and fatten each interval at each subdivision by $\epsilon/2^n$ (except endpoints).  The resulting collection is uncountable, and I have no idea why you really want it, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You want the measures of the subsets to converge to $0$, but the sum of the measures to diverge.

Take any sequence of positive reals whose terms go to $0$ such that the sum diverges. Let this be $\{a_i\}$. Let $p_i$ be the partial sum $p_i=\sum_{n=0}^i a_n$. Then consider the sequence of subsets $[p_i (\text{mod} 2\pi), p_{i+1} (\text{mod} 2\pi))$ on the circle where we identify $0$ and $2\pi$. The number of times $x$ is covered by the intervals up to $[p_{i-1},p_i)$ is about $p_i/2\pi$, and since this goes to $\infty$, every $x$ is covered infinitely often.